# DateFrom DateTo Format

Tags: nba-api

I'm currently trying to use the endpoint player game logs in order to retrieve the game stat of a specific player throw a particular period of time.

so I want to use the attributes `date_from_nullable` and `date_to_nullable` and the problem is I always get an error

I wonder what is the correct format for these two attributes?

Answer (score 2):

"m/d/yyyy"

Example: start='10/6/2019', end='10/7/2019'